# How to get more lines of context in Github

Tags: github, diff

In github commit viewer or pull request viewer, or the compare view, can I have it show more lines of context around the diffs?

Using git cli, I'd do git diff -U100 (or however many lines of context I wanted).

I checked out help.github.com with no luck (lines of context doesn't even show up). Other diff viewers usually do this, and other code review tools usually do this. And Github has all kinds of hidden features, so I figured there might be a hidden feature here. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Github just released a feature for doing this by clicking in the gutter of a diff view: https://github.com/blog/1705-expanding-context-in-diffs

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** This feature exist now https://github.com/blog/1705-expanding-context-in-diffs

I sent a feature request to github about this some month ago and got this answer:

> Mattias,
>
> Thanks for the feedback. Rest assured we know the diff display could be improved, since we feel this same pain quite a bit. We have Ideas™.
>
> Yossef

So lets hope they come up with something nice.

Answer (score 2):

I also sent a feature request to github with a similar response, but in the meantime have been using mridgway's github-expand-diff FF/chrome greasemonkey script, which works pretty nicely:

https://github.com/mridgway/github-expand-diff